# Configure static IP scope via nmcli

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I'm trying to setup a network bridge on a server using nmcli.
The bridge should have multiple configured static IP addresses with a `scope link`.

This is easily done via `ip` command like so: `ip addr add 192.168.0.150/24 dev br0 scope link`

But I can't seem to find how to do this using nmcli only?
Adding a static IP goes like this:

`nmcli connection modify br0 ipv4.addresses '192.168.0.150/24'`

But how should I configure the scope here?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you working with? Is it a Desktop or Server setup?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 server at this moment